# Anthos config management Prometheus metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, prometheus, metrics, google-anthos

How to enable the Prometheus metrics for Anthos Config Management(ACM). version 1.7.X.
This document is not clear, because most of these steps seem in place from the ACM file.
https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/docs/how-to/monitoring-config-sync.

Answer (score 1):

ACM emits the metrics by itself on default port 8675. We do not have to open up the port. This https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/docs/how-to/monitoring-config-sync document guide us for setting up of new Prometheus.
If you have already Already Prometheus operator you, just you have create a serviceMonitor for Prometheus to scrape the Metrics.